# How to match a string with words with either 'and' or 'or' between the words?

Tags: java, regex

I have following string with words with either word `and` or word `or` between.

```
Apple and Mango or Banana or Lichi and Potato or blackberry
```

Please guide me how to create a regular expression to match strings with 1 or more words with `and` or `or` between the words.

Comment: what do you want from that?

Comment: How many words? Are "and" and "or" fixed? That is, do you want this pattern: word + and + word + or + word + or + word + and + word + or + word. Or do you want any number of words separated by "and"/"or"?

Comment: I want to match the above mentioned string with regular expression.

Comment: any number of words separated by "and"/"or".

Comment: did you want to match this line `Apple and Mango Banana Lichi`?

Comment: did you want to match the whole line or only the strings which are separated by and or or?

Comment: Care to accept my answer if it helped? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\w+( (and|or) \w+)*
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in following way:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Apple and Mango or Banana or Lichi and Potato or blackberry".split("and|or")));
```

**Output**

> [Apple ,  Mango ,  Banana ,  Lichi ,  Potato ,  blackberry]

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you know it .. String#Split uses a regular expression only.

Comment: Oh, now I wasn't clear enough, sorry :D I meant he wants to MATCH the string, not split it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "Apple and Mango or Banana or Lichi and Potato or blackberry";
    String fruit = "(Apple|Banana|blackberry|Lichi|Mango|Potato)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + fruit + " (and|or) )+" + fruit);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Matches");
        int n = m.groupCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n", i, m.group(i));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match");
    }

Matches
[1] Potato or 
[2] Potato
[3] or
[4] blackberry
```

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for information and an explanation.