# XSLT 2.0 if then

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In XSLT 2.0, can we use if then only means no else clause.
`<Employee><Status><xsl:value-of select="if (tns:Employee/tns:EmpId = 4) then 'new' else 'old'"/></Status></Employee>`
Here if I don't want else clause, means if empid is not 4, then do not populate Status field. what will be xslt?

Comment: Well, after Googling it and thinkng it over: what *would* the value be if there is no `else`? Reorder things to avoid the situation.

Comment: By "don't populate the status field" do you mean you want an empty `<Status/>` or do you want no Status element at all?

Comment: What's the connection to yor [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29633276/1987598)? Why do you ask very similar questions with a different XML input? Also, some of your older questions need your attention: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29633276/1987598, http://stackoverflow.com/q/22759983/1987598 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/24752681/1987598. Either accept an answer to them or otherwise react to the answers given.

Comment: I want no Status element at all.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm reading the question wrong, just add an empty string or empty sequence.

Example...

```
if (tns:Employee/tns:EmpId = 4) then 'new' else ''
```

or

```
if (tns:Employee/tns:EmpId = 4) then 'new' else ()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.This will create <Status/> but if I need not to create the status field what will be the solution.

Comment: @user3480752 - If you don't want a status element output at all you can use an xsl:if like suggested by Tim C or you might be able to narrow the original scope of what you're processing. It's hard to give an example though when your question does not contain a complete example of your XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any `status` at all, you can easily achieve this with the standard `xsl:if` in XSLT (available in all versions)

```
<Employee>
    <xsl:if test="tns:Employee/tns:EmpId = 4">
      <Status>new</Status>
    </xsl:if>
</Employee>
```